# how to retrieve data from indexeddb and show in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a function readAll() which is fetching data into the todos div but it is not showing data on the click function but it is not working data is adding successfully in the index db but it is not showing. Now I first i have empty the table after that I just have append the data into the html from the javascript.

```
function readAll() {
  var objectStore = db.transaction("todostore").objectStore("todostore");
  $("#todos").empty();
  objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
   var cursor = event.target.result;
   if (cursor) {
    $("#todos").append("<tr><td>" + cursor.key + "</td><td>" + cursor.value.todo + "</td><td><button onclick=\"update('" + cursor.key + "','" + cursor.value.todo + "')\">Update</button></td><td><button onclick=\"removetodo('" + cursor.key + "','" + cursor.value.todo + "')\">Delete</button></td></tr>");
    cursor.continue();
  }
 };
};
```

now I am calling the function on the click I am just calling the readAll Function

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
  readAll();
});
```

I have created a div of id view inside the div i have use  a table head now I am just appending the code from the JavaScript and populate into the html

```
<div id="view">
 <thead>
   <tr class="ui-bar-d">
     <th data-priority="2">Timestamp</th>
     <th data-priority="1">To Do</th>
     <th data-priority="3">Update</th>
     <th data-priority="4">Delete</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="todos">
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<label for="todo">To Do:</label>
<input id="todo" type="text">
<input id="toprice" type="text">
<button class="clickme">clickme</button>
<button class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: your html is malformed.

Comment: can you tell me where is the mistake

Comment: missing <table> tag looked like.

Comment: not working still

Comment: @tayyabvohra where you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As IDB is async.You will need to call you're function in ....

```
 transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
      $(".clickme").click(function(){
      readAll();
   });     
  };
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction/oncomplete